# Style for pills in navbar

Tags: html, css

How can i make custom pills for navbar like on 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqAmS.png)?

I did it by [myself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tfPt.png), but pills are inside of navbar and the text is not in the center of pill.

I understand, that the problem is inside of `.menu li a:hover:not` and `.menu li a:hover:not(.active)`. But i don't know, how to make outside of navbar(i mean borders of the pills like on screenshot)

```css
.menu {
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto; 
}

.menu ul {
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 list-style:none;
 border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
 background-color: #0b78ad;
 text-align: center;
}

.menu li {
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
}

.menu ul li a {
 padding: 10px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 margin: 0px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}

.menu li a:hover:not(.active) {
 color: #325491;
}

.menu li.active a {
    border-radius: 20px 0 20px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #325491;
    color: #325491;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
  <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">startseite</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">über uns</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">zell-linien</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: No use just posting pictures. Please provide your code in the question

Comment: @Evhenii Share the code you have done till now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.menu {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.menu ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #0b78ad;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 34px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.menu li {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 18px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.menu ul li a.active,
.menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #0b78ad;
  color: #0b78ad;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Skill</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you do? Why does this work? Explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with just a plain `border-radius`, like any other property it starts with `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `right`

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ededed;
  border: 1px solid deepskyblue;
  border-radius: 10px 0 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">shape</div>
```

Comment: The problem is, that borders are inside of navbar and i don't know, how to make it outside of navbar

Comment: @EvheniiVasylenko post your html

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.
1. Navbar you can give a 'max-height' property so that we can set a height for the first-child.

```
    #nav-id {
      max-height: 65px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

2.We can set the first 'li' 'margin-top' or 'position'

```
    li:first-child {
    border-radius: 15px 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 106px;
    background: blue;
  background-position: center; 
  margin-top:-20px;
z-index:1;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Here is the working copy:
https://codepen.io/nabanitadasgupta/pen/aLNGgo